# Error Thread 1: "-[entity_name relation_name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003812bc0"

Tags: base-de-datos, ios, swift, xcode, iphone

Me encuentro este error después de asegurar que he creado un objeto con el correspondiente atributo, en este caso una relación. El problema viene de una relación entre 2 entidades: GroupData y TopicData. Las relaciones son como se ve en las imágenes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para utilizar un context tengo una función que llamo DataController:

```
import CoreData


class DataController: ObservableObject {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "vocabul-R")



    init() {

        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in

                if let error = error {

                    print("CoreData failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                }

        }

        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump

        container.viewContext.retainsRegisteredObjects = true



    }

}
```

Primero creo los objetos a partir de datos que saco de archivos csv. Depurando el código he asegurado que los objetos que creo tienen los valores correspondientes para cada atributo y los objetos correctos en las relaciones.

```
guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: data_file, ofType: "csv") else {
        return
    }

    let dataController = DataController()

    let context = dataController.container.viewContext
    do {
        try context.save()
        }
    catch {
    }

    var data = ""
    do {
        data = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")

    rows.remove(at: 0)

    for row in rows {

        let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")

        let name = columns[0]

        let activation_level = (columns[1] as NSString).integerValue

        let activated: Bool = false

        let last_opened_group: Int16 = 0

        let current_level: Int16 = 0

        let topic = TopicData(context: context)

        topic.name = name

        topic.activated = activated

        topic.activationLevel = Int16(activation_level)

        topic.last_opened_group = last_opened_group

        topic.current_level = current_level

        do {
            try context.save()
            }
        catch {
            print("Context not saved")
        }
    }
}

func parseCSV_groups (data_file: String, topic_name: String) {
    guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: data_file, ofType: "csv") else {
        return
    }
    var data = ""
    do {
        data = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")

    rows.remove(at: 0)

    let dataController = DataController()

    let context = dataController.container.viewContext

    let topic = TopicData.getTopicFromName(name: topic_name, context: context)

    let train_list = Train_list(context: context)

    let test_list = Test_list(context: context)

    train_list.train_list = "train_list"

    test_list.test_list = "test_list"

    for row in rows {
        let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
        let index_group = (columns[0] as NSString).integerValue
        let mean_level = (columns[1] as NSString).integerValue
        let cleared_words: Int16 = 0
        let group = GroupData(context: context)
        group.index_group = Int16(index_group)
        group.mean_level = Int16(mean_level)
        group.cleared_words = cleared_words
        //group.topic = topic
        topic.addToGroup(group)
        do {
            try context.save()
            }
        catch {
            print("Context not saved")
        }
    }
}
```

He creado objetos para las dos entidades con relaciones. Tengo otras funciones con relaciones entre estas y otras entidades y parece que funcionan bien. Pero ahora necesito obtener todos los grupos que un TopicData tiene. Para ello, obtengo un topic a partir de su nomber.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<TopicData>(entityName: "TopicData")

        
let topics = (try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)) ?? []

let topic = topics.first ?? TopicData()

return topic
```

Esto parece que funciona ya que puedo por ejemplo preguntar qué tipo de objeto es topic y obtengo TopicData. Pero luego intento obtener qué grupos tiene y me da error.

```
let groups = topic.groups
```

(También he intentado topic!)
Tampoco funciona usar un fetchRequest:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "topic = %@", topic)

let groups = (try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)) ?? []
```

También obtengo error si intento obtener uno de los atributos (activated) de algún topic.

Pensé que esto podía estar pasando porque cada vez que actualizo un TopicData y lo vuelvo a guardar en el context, un TopicData diferente se estaría creando sin la relación con group. Pero añadí un constraint a TopicData en name para que no hubiese 2 objetos con el mismo y no funcionó. Otra cosa que pensé es que las relaciones podrían estar desapareciendo, que es algo que he visto que mucha gente tenía este problema por este motivo. Pero añadí la línea de retainsRegisteredObjects en DataController y tampoco funcionó.
El error completo es: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TopicData group]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003812bc0' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Creo que esto es todo. Si hay algo más del código que podría ser útil lo puedo añadir. Gracias!

Edit: clase tras la cual ya no puedo usar topic.group

```
    guard let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: data_file, ofType: "csv") else {

        return

    }

    

    var data = ""

    do {

        data = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath)

    } catch {

        return

    }

    

    var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")

    rows.remove(at: 0)

    let dataController = DataController()

    let context = dataController.container.viewContext

    

    let topic = TopicData.getTopicFromName(name: topic_name, context: context)

    

    

    for row in rows {

        let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")

        

        let name = columns[0]

        let translation = columns[1]

        let group_index = (columns[2] as NSString).integerValue

        let previous_guessed: Bool = false

        let character: Character = "?"

        

        let group = GroupData.getGroupFromIndexAndTopic(index: Int16(group_index), topic: topic, context: context)

        

        

        var already_shown: Bool = false

        

        if translation.contains(character) {

            already_shown = true

        }

        let word = Word(context: context)

        word.namew = name

        word.translation = translation

        word.previous_guessed = previous_guessed

        //word.group = group

        

        group.addToWord(word)

        word.already_shown = already_shown

        

        do {

            try context.save()

            }

        catch {

            print("Context not saved")

        }

    }
```

Y para añadir word:

```
static func getGroupFromIndexAndTopic(index: Int16, topic: TopicData, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> GroupData {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<GroupData>(entityName: "GroupData")

        

        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "index_group = %d AND topic = %@", index, topic)



        let groups = (try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)) ?? []

        let group = groups.first!

        return group

    }
```

Comment: He simulado tu modelo de CoreData con datos quemados ya que no tengo el csv y tampoco `topic.addToGroup` y no tengo el error que mencionas. Puede ser algo dentro de `addToGroup` que supongo la creaste.

Comment: @Bicho Gracias por el comentario. topic.addToGroup es una función que se genera automáticamente con Create NSManagedObject Subclass. He visto que el error no aparece tras usar la función en la que creo los group. Aparece tras usar otra función en la que creo objetos de otra entidad llamada Word (la he añadido). Para crearlos necesito relacionarlos con group, así que también obtengo Topic y Group. Las funciones para obtener topic y group parece que funcionan bien. La de topic ya estaba, pero añado la de group también. La otra función addToWord también es autogenerada.